How to call every batch file in one dir (one by one)?
I want to create a folder called plug-ins so my batch program will load (call) all of them.
I expect it to load all files one by one not all at once, and after it finishes every single one it needs to return to the main batch file.
So far I tried using
call *.bat
And that is not really working. :/

for %%G in (*.bat) do call "%%G"

This is just an example:
In the Plug-Ins folder there are 2 bat files: called1.bat and called2.bat.
I named the bat file called is caller.bat. It is located anywhere other than in the Plug-Ins folder.

caller.bat

@Echo Off
For %%A in ("C:\Temp\plug-ins\*.bat") do call "%%A"
rem For %%A in (".\plug-ins\*.bat") do call "%%A"
pause


called1.bat:

@Echo Off
echo This is Called 1
Exit /B


called2.bat:

@Echo Off
echo This is Called 2
Exit /B

The output will:
This is Called 1
This is Called 2
Press any key to continue . . .

In the case of calling a batch file, in order to return to the caller, at the end of each called bat file use Exit /B
